# SPSite currentSite using try/catch block

Tags: development

What is a better approach when it comes to writing code for sharepoint 2010 applications:

```
 using (SPSite currentSite = new SPSite("SiteName"))
 {
     using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
     {
        try{...}
        catch{...}
     }
 }
```

or

```
try 
{
  using (SPSite currentSite = new SPSite("SiteName"))
  {
     using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
     {
        ....
     }
  }

}

catch{...}
```

? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Writing try catch as outer element is better practice. You make SPSite / SPWeb connection calls handled safe by adding it inside try catch block.

```
try 
{
  using (SPSite currentSite = new SPSite("SiteName"))
  {
     using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
     {
        ....
     }
  }
}   
catch{...}
```

To make it more specific you can do a nested code.

```
try 
{
  using (SPSite currentSite = new SPSite("SiteName"))
  {
     using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
     {
        try{

        }
        catch(Exception){}
     }
  }
}   
catch{...}
```